# Can't move object: object moves back to original place in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a very simple drawing in Inkscape. It consists of a path in heart shape and I have a circle, filled red. I can neither scale nor move the red circle and I can't figure out why.

Here's my drawing:

[image: Inkscape drawing]

I have tried:

- unlocking the object. But as you can see in the objects panel, the object is already unlocked. If it is locked, I can't even drag it around. However, dragging is possible.
- changing the position by modifying the X and Y coordinates in the textbox. While I can enter text, it restets back to the old values as soon as I press Enter.
- deleting the circle and creating a new one. The new circle has the same restriction.

I'm using Inkscape 0.92.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. I can't see anything obviously wrong. Perhaps you could share the SVG?  Make sure you are using the most recent Inkscape 0.92.2, just in case it's a bug in an old version.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with a multi-line text object, but it was definitely *not* related to snapping. People with the same problem may be interested in https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/1455

Answer (score 2):

Disable <kbd>Snap nodes, Paths, and Handles</kbd> button - yes, it's just one button, its on the top second layer of options.